# Rendering more than one RadioButton.Group in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following two arrays:

```
const items =[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "groupId": 1,
        "name": "product1",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "groupId": 1,
        "name": "product2",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "groupId": 2,
        "name": "product3",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "groupId": 2,
        "name": "product4",
        "price": 10
    }
];

 const category = [
        {
            "name": "optional",
            "id": 1,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "required",
            "id": 2,
            "type": 1
        },
    ]
```

So, what I am doing I take the category name from array category then after displaying the name of category I am rendering the item that belong to that category from the items array when category.id = items.groupId I did the following to achieve that:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
     {category.map(category => {
        
       return(<>
      <Text> {category.name}</Text>
       {items.filter(product => product.groupId === category.id).map(b => {
          return(<>

              <RadioButton.Group
                  key={b.groupId}
                  value={value}
                  onValueChange={value => { setValue(value) }}
                                        
                >
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                     <RadioButton.Item
                         key={b.id}
                         mode='android'
                         label={b.name}
                         value={b.name}
                      />
                       <Text>${b.price}</Text>
                 </View>
               </RadioButton.Group>
          </>)
         
     })
 }
     </>) })}
    
    </View>
```

the problem I am facing is that when i check on of the item in the first group and then i check another item in the second group the value in first group is unchecked. I spent several hours trying to solve it but I'm unable to make it work. the library for radioButtons is RadioButton from 'react-native-paper';

here is a working example in expo having the same problem
https://snack.expo.dev/u389TXW5v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the useState line inside the categories map. like this:

```
...
{items.filter(product => product.groupId === category.id).map(b => {
      const [value,setValue] = useState(''); // <----- ADDITION
      return(<>

          <RadioButton.Group
              key={b.groupId}
...
```